# How to save a line break into a plist NSArray?

Tags: nsstring, save, nsarray, plist, newline

I am trying to save an NSArray into a plist such that each element of the array is a string with line breaks.

I understand that the plist can be edited directly by hitting option +enter keys.

But I need to save the NSString with line breaks into the array so that when read back into a tableview  all I get is the part of the string before line break.

So far I have tried adding /n, /r/n, /n/n

[image: tableview]

the plist looks like this:

[image: plist]

The first element is a string with line breaks, how can I get 20,5,100 on newlines?

Thank you very much, any advise is much appreciated!

Comment: There are no line breaks in your string. The backslashes are - probably mistakenly - escaped.

Comment: What's the right way to add a line break to a string, so that it will be read as a line break in the plist array element? Thanks!

Comment: without escaping the backslash. Like this: `\n`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, i have tried \n, and still appears like:
test \n 20 \n 5 \n 100.